# Functional characterization of local correlation matrices?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, computational-complexity, random-matrices, quantum-computation

*Definition:* A matrix $C\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is local correlation matrix iff there exists real random variables $x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n$ defined on a common probability space which takes values in $[-1,+1]$ such that $$C_{ij}=\mathbb E[x_iy_j]$$ holds at every $(i,j)\in\{1,\dots,m\}\times\{1,\dots,n\}$.

1. What are some of non-trivial geometric or functional characterization of set of all $m\times n$ local correlation matrices?
2. Is there a simple polynomial, randomized polynomial or quantum polynomial test to determine if a given $m\times n$ matrix is local correlation matrix?